# Lyapunov's direct method proof: show that $V(x(t)) \rightarrow 0$ implies $x(t) \rightarrow 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

In proofs of Lyapunov's direct method (see [this lecture, pg 8](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-241j-dynamic-systems-and-control-spring-2011/readings/MIT6_241JS11_chap13.pdf) for example), the claim is made that because of continuity of $V$, to show $x(t) \rightarrow 0$, it suffices to show that $V(x(t)) \rightarrow 0$. Why is this true?

Continuity implies that if $\Vert x \Vert < \delta$ then $V(x) <\epsilon$ for appropriate $(\delta, \epsilon)$, but it seems like here we want to show that another relation also holds, that if $V(x) < \delta_0$ then $\Vert x \Vert < \epsilon_0$ for some appropriate $(\delta_0, \epsilon_0)$.

I'm aware that if $g(t)$ converges as $t \rightarrow \infty$ and $f$ is continuous then $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} f(g(t)) = f(\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} g(t))$ but I don't think we can assume $x(t)$ converges: that's one of the results we are trying to prove!

Comment: Note that as long as you do not assume that $V(x)$ is radially unbounded the conclusion is only local.

Comment: What I mean is that if $|x|<D$ (local) and $V(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=0$ then there exist $v>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that $V(x)<v \Rightarrow |x|<\delta$, i.e., the values of $V$ below $v$ can be only in a neigbrhood of the origin.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that makes sense intuitively but I'm struggling to prove it formally

Comment: Ok. 

Claim: for $|x|<D$ and $V(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=0$ there exists $v>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that $V(x)<v$ implies $|x|<\delta$.

Question 1. Can you prove this claim on your own?

Question 2. Given this claim, can you show that $V\to 0$ implies $|x|\to 0$?